# Read a specific row from excel based on the input

Tags: python

I want to read a row from an excel sheet based on the user input. My excel sheet contains columns with number, priority, assignee and other details.
Eg:- if I want to fetch the entire row of data for number= PRB00000, I am currently doing that with the below code. I am using a list and manually finding the index of it and hard-coding it to a VARIABLE and then sending it to selenium webdriver eg:- webelement.send_keys(variable). I don't want to do that and instead read the row based on user input and store the values in respective columns names.

```
book=xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\third party power.xlsx')
#print (book.nsheets)
#print (book.sheet_names())

first_sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
prb= "PRB0045087"
list1 = []
for sheet in book.sheets():
 for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
     row=sheet.row(rowidx)
     for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
         if cell.value == prb :
             list1 = first_sheet.row_values(rowidx)

   RCA = list1[20]
   LTF = list1[21]
```

Comment: I am not sure what selenium has to do with this, since your code doesn't include any selenium.

Comment: i have it in my code. i need help only on the excel reading part. forget about the selenium.  i can handle that.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid my selenium code                                                            ` rc=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
rc.click()
rc.send_keys(dict_data.RCA)

ltf=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='tinymce']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
ltf.click()
ltf.send_keys(dict_data.LTF)`

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you do a dictionary of IDs and row index, that way you can look it up

```
ids = {cell.value:colidx for colidx,cell in enumerate(row)}
```